# Pig Latin Parameter Regex Match

Tags: apache-pig

I have a filter in my pig script that should basically either take a value from the command line or if no command is provided should just assume  no filtering and proceed.

Example, the line in the  script is as :

```
b = FILTER a by STATE matches '$VALUEMATCH';
```

In the command line, I may provide:

```
pig -param VALUEMATCH='VA' SCRIPT.pig
```

If i don't provide this in the command line, I basically want the script to continue using all values of STATE.

So basically want the  %default VALUEMATCH to be all.So, what should the correct default statement be?

```
%default VALUEMATCH = '*'
```

does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `=` and use `.*`

```
%default VALUEMATCH '.*'
```